# Sentiment Analysis, polarity score output repeating several times instead of appearing once

Tags: python

I have an issue with my polarity score. When I'm extracting the sentiment from a sentence, it prints the sentiment 14 times instead of just once.

I'm having trouble deducting the source of the issue. Can any of you help me?

My coding looks like the following :

```py
  text_data='Du er ikke rar'
```

```py
pos=0
neg=0
neu=0

for text in text_data:
  analysis=SV.sentida(text_data)

  if analysis > 0:
    print('positiv')
    print("--"*20)
    pos=pos+1
  elif analysis == 0:
    print('neutral')
    print("--"*20)
    neu=neu+1
  else:
    print('negativ')
    print("--"*20)
    neg=neg+1

print(text_data)
print("--"*10)
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
negativ
----------------------------------------
negativ
----------------------------------------
negativ
----------------------------------------
negativ
----------------------------------------
negativ
----------------------------------------
negativ
----------------------------------------
negativ
----------------------------------------
negativ
----------------------------------------
negativ
----------------------------------------
negativ
----------------------------------------
negativ
----------------------------------------
negativ
----------------------------------------
negativ
----------------------------------------
negativ
----------------------------------------
Du er ikke rar
--------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

This `for text in text_data:` makes you iterate over every letter in your string: D,u, ,e,r, ,i,k,k,e ...

That is why you have so many outputs.